# HTML appearing div makes a scrollbar appear

Tags: html, overflow

I have a webpage with a layer that appears which has height 500px. Inside this layer I have a normal webpage that has a hidden div. On clicking on a link in this layer this div appears, but a scrollbar in the layer appears too. I would like that the appearing of this div doesn't make the scrollbar appear, that is, this div simply appears over the page...

I hope I've been clear, it's really hard to explain.

Thanks all

EDIT:

I cannot post the code of the page because it's more than 800 lines long.

I try to explain myself a bit better:
I have this page full of text with in the middle a hidden div. Of course when the visibility = block is set for this div, it appears right where I want, but since it's in the middle the page becomes "longer" and an overflow appears, and overflow: hidden doesn't do the job :(.

Comment: This sounds like an overflow issue to me, but could you please post the code.

Comment: And a screenshot, if it's not too much of an effort.

Comment: please show some code...le sigh

Comment: The code is sadly too long to show, I might consider posting a screen but since is a project for what i'm paid i don't know if i can actually post screens.

Comment: What, exactly do you mean by "layer". Is it a <div>? An <iframe>? A <layer>?

Comment: it's a div that appears, with height 500 px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but won't **overflow: hidden** do the job?